# Is it possible to buy a better 12v battery for kids ride on?

Tags: batteries

My kids have a 12v ride on train. The battery is not lasting very long at all, after one lap of the garden it is going too slow. I don't want it to necessarily go faster, just for the battery to last longer. Is it possible to buy a better 12v battery??

---

Added: (RM)

An edit along the following lines **MAY** be useful:

My kids have a 12v ride on train. The battery is not lasting very long at all, after one lap of the garden it is going too slow.

I wish to design a better battery system for it.
The new system should allows longer operation between recharges.
The existing battery consists of a 12V battery type xxx (8 cells type / 1 s SLA xx Ah / ...) and fits in a space sized xxx x xxx x xxx.
External mounting of a new battery system up to a size of say X x Y x Z and weight xxx would be acceptable.

Additional speed is not required.
How would I design a battery system tomeed my needs.

Comment: Assumin the battery is a lead acid battery, then one of greater Ah will last longer. LA batteries usually have the Ah capacity market on them. Can you post battery specification or a photo or reference to a photo. Se[many examples here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=1075&q=lead+acid+battery&oq=lead+acid+battery&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2558.9836.0.10381.17.10.0.7.7.0.227.1959.2-9.9.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.60.img..1.16.1976.e-STjcLFFO8#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=12v+lead+acid+battery+)

Comment: NB - if they close your question you can modify it and ask questions in comments after it is closed. The question needs to be framed as an electrical design one to make it properly site relevant AND we must know the specs of the existing battery to be helpful. A photo of the train and/or existing battery (or a link) would help.

Comment: This was closed due to typical bs. This is a valid question on modifying electronics as defined in the scope. At worst, it's a duplicate. Vote to reopen

Answer (score 4):

Your train may use a number of separate batteries (typically 8 x "1.5V" batteries) or a single 12V battery.

If it is a single battery it will probably be a "Lead Acid" (LA) battery (similar to what cars usually use.There are other options but LA is the most likely.

Assuming the battery is a lead acid battery, then one of greater "Ampere Hour" (Ah) capacity  will last longer.
LA batteries usually have the Ah capacity market on them.
Can you post battery specification or a photo or reference to a photo.

See many [12V lead acid battery examples here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=1075&q=lead+acid+battery&oq=lead+acid+battery&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2558.9836.0.10381.17.10.0.7.7.0.227.1959.2-9.9.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.60.img..1.16.1976.e-STjcLFFO8#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=12v+lead+acid+battery+).
If your battery is not a LA battery then using one of higher capacity than you have now will help. You may not be able to fit the battery in the space available. A larger capacity battery could usually be accommodated elsewhere on the train without making it look too bad.

Here is a small LA battery as an example.
560g weight.
Dimensions: 95mm x 47mm x 49mm
From here http://www.a1decoy.co.uk/12v-12-ah-battery-sla-542-p.asp
and MUCH too dear.  For the same money you can get a battery substantially larger in capacity.

[These ones are in Bewdley](http://www.strikalite.co.uk/prodcat_type/5/ALL/0/Sealed_Lead_Acid_batteries.html)  and they have a range of sizes.

[This 7 Ah one is in Portsmouth at a good price for the size](http://www.freeads.co.uk/uk/buy__sell/leisure__hobbies/toys,_games__gadgets/batteries__chargers/26886941/ultra-max-12v-7ah-pre-charged-battery/view#.VKPySSuUfYE)
This is quite a large battery and is quite likely not to fit in the train BUT if you can work out how to accommodate it will do the job very well indeed.

A photo of the train and battery and a description of the existing battery would help greatly.
What price range did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can buy a battery that has the same voltage, but greater capacity (amp-hours).

Since you have told us nothing at all about the existing battery or the product it's used in, we can't give you any more specific advice than that.